# Typing suggestion for contracts within brownie

Tags: python, blockchain, brownie

I was started with brownie and I found out that contracts, for my case it is `SimpleStorage`, are being imported from brownie itself,

> from brownie import SimpleStorage

But thing is that there are no typing suggestions and also import tagged as `unknown import`. Are there any possible solutions?

*for reference, I was using **vs code** and it is set to default python language server **Pylance***.